# Change the route for a Restangular object

Tags: restangular

I'm using Restangular to login my currentUser like this:

```
  this.login = function (credentials) {

    var loginURL = Restangular.all('logins');

    return loginURL.customPOST({ user: credentials.user, password: credentials.password })
      .then(function (res) {
         $scope.currentUser = res;
         console.log("User successfully logged in.");
      };
   };
```

At some point the currentUser might need to update his preferences with a customPUT() . . .

```
  this.updateUser = function(currentUser){

    return currentUser.customPUT({ user: currentUser })
      .then(function(response){
        if (typeof response.errors === 'undefined') {
          $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.updateAccount, response.data );
          console.log("Account successfully updated.");
          currentUser = response.data
        } else {
          $q.reject(response);
        }
      }, function(response){
        $q.reject(response);
      });
```

My problem is that my server api has a one route for logins/outs (`/api/logins/`) and a different route for user updates (`/api/users/`).

Is there a way to easily change the route on my currentUser object after login so that it uses the `/api/users` route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume

- that you have set the `baseUrl` (via `Restangular.setBaseUrl`) to your API
- and that the route `'users'` is needed most of the time.

If this is true, one solution would be to take the plain object returned by the login and [re-restangularize](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#restangular-methods) it. This can look similar to following code:

```
    $scope.currentUser = res.plain();
    Restangular.restangularizeElement('', $scope.currentUser, 'users');
```

Try this in the `then`-part of your login POST. Afterwards `$scope.currentUser` should be your user object, but all set up like you've retrieved it from `/users`. Subsequent REST-operations will then use the new URL.